# visual studio online for vs express 2010

Tags: express, visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to use VSO in Microsoft Visual web Developer 2010 express?
or Is there any alternative for keeping log of my project? its just me, not any other team member.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

However, there is one drawback that sounds like a massive deal breaker to me. Running Unit tests with Visual Studio 2010 is not possible.

the integrated MSTest feature does not seem to be included. It’s not in the menu, and the ASP.NET MVC2 template comes without the test project it normally includes. Well, I could live 
in Express Edition, you cannot attach the debugger to NUnit. I would try to install visual studio 2013 because it has cloud and contain VSO, and log to keep track of your project as a team.

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235233

Comment: you can try it, i am not sure if 2010 express has that capability.